# Confused about Etihad baggage policy

Tags: luggage, etihad

I recently booked a flight to Germany on Etihad Airways. I have been reading their FAQ and I am a little confused about their baggage policy. This is what is stated on their website:
[image]
Can someone help me understand this. I booked the ticket under Economy (not Economy Flex) so I am allowed to carry 30kg. Is there a limit on the number of bags that I can carry?. Or does the combined weight of all bags must be 30kg?.

Comment: Not sure how many bags you are allowed but 30kg is the combined maximum weight, meaning you can take one bag up to 30kg but it does not say if you would be allowed to check in 3 bags of 10kg instead.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you bought your tickets after 31-1-2018, if so, [the limits on this site](https://www.etihad.com/en/before-you-fly/baggage-information/allowances/allowances-before-january-2018/) are what you need to work with.

As you can see, it has different limits based on different destinations, that is size limits, and there are number limits depending on where you fly to.

If you do not fly to one of the exception destinations, these are the rules:

> Economy Deals and Economy Saver Fare Choices: 1 bag, up to 23kg
>   Economy Classic and Economy Flex Fare Choices: 2 bags, up to 23kg each

Most of the exceptions have a lower level of 2 bags up to 23 kg each, but they mostly do not show the Economy fare you mentioned.
I guess the information you found is older, there were new rules in 2018 but also in 2015, and the rules seem to go toward one bag with a maximum of 23 kg.